# when numbers are not in order

Tags: word-request, collocations

Here's the situation: I was taking notes in my notebook on the new phrases I get to see in an English series when I noticed I accidentally skipped one of the episodes so in my notebook I had episode number 4 but it was actually episode number 5 which was assigned to 4. And now I'm writing 4 after 5 in my notebook. Here I wondered how to describe it in English the thing that happened in my notebook. I assigned the wrong numbers. Here my sentence by which I want to mean **4 is in the place of 5 and 5 is in the place of 4** so basically it's 1, 2, 3, 5, 4. My thought was

> Number 4 and 5 are swapped.

Does it make sense? Is it the right way to say this? I know it's a piece of cake for a native speaker but I can't be sure.

Comment: Those numbers are "out of sequence."

Comment: @Robusto isn't it too general? I mean 2,1,4,5,7,3 are also out of sequence with 6 missing altogether. Is there a word to say they're in place of each other? Or saying 5 and 4 are out of sequence suffices and makes that meaning?

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, *swapped* is the word you're looking for. *Reversed* might work as well.

Comment: 4 and 5 are inverted.

Comment: @Robusto _4 and 5 are reversed_ or _4 and 5 are swapped_ are fine to native speakers' ear? sorry I have this obsession to make sure :)

Comment: **_Transposed_** is the word you want here. "4 and 5 are _transposed_ in the series." This is idiomatic.

Comment: Yes "swapped", or "switched".

Comment: @Absolute Beginner interesting I didn't know _invert_ can be used here. always thought it's to describe something upside down. please if you're sure about it post it as an answer and I'll sure upvote it.

Comment: @P. E. Dant that just blew me away :) I've never heard of such a word in my life. Thank you.

Comment: "Inverted" is not idiomatic at all. "Swapped" is a little informal. Yep, "Transposed" is the word here, @Yuri . Glad to help.